# Throwing errors in a dialog box

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to throw an error (user defined and not the netLogo runtime error )  if one button is pressed before the other.
I have three buttons " SETUP" , "CONFIGURE", " SIMULATE" . I want to throw an error if SIMULATE is clicked before CONFIGEURE.
I know there is a primitive available " user-message" as mentioned by Sir.Seth Tisue in my other question, but do not know how to include it for my situaton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a global `configured?`. Have `configure` set it to true. Then in `simulate`, put:

```
if configured? != true [
  user-message "You must press configure first"
  stop
]
```